# when using ignite for cache, what is difference between using Ignite Cache Queries and using IgniteRepository class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ignite

when using ignite for cache, what is difference between using Ignite Cache Queries and using IgniteRepository class?

Ignite Cache Queries can CRUD data from the Ignite cache, and IgniteRepository can the same by method. What is difference?

Answer (score 2):

They're just different ways of accessing the same data. If you already use or like Spring Data you can use IgniteRepository. If not, you can use Ignite's APIs directly. Or you can mix-and-match.